# Why is the output 1 bigger than it should be? (assembly)

Tags: assembly, mips

My code:

```
.data 
x: .word 1
y: .word 1
z: .word 1

.text 
main:
lw $t0, x 
lw $t1, y
lw $t2, z 

add $t0, $t0, $t1   # t0= x+y
add $t0, $t0, $t2   # t0= x+y+z

add $a0, $a0, $t0

li $v0, 1
syscall 

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

i am adding 1 to 1 to 1. The answer should be 3, but it is 4.
Even when im using big numbers, the answer is alwasys 1 bigger that it should be.
why is it so?

Comment: What is $a0 at the start? 1 maybe?

Comment: Than you! 
i used 
sub $a0, $a0, $a0
at the beginning of main and it worked. Im just wondering why $a0 was at 1, i never initialized it.. at least i think so

Comment: On a real CPU many registers may have any value at the start. $a0 might have the value 12353224 when starting the program...

Answer (score 0):

To do `$a0 = $t0`, use `move $a0, $t0`.

What you wrote adds your value to the old value of `$a0` for no reason or benefit, like `$a0 += $t0`.  You wouldn't write that in a high-level language with an uninitialized variable; don't do it in asm.  Obviously `$a0` was `1` for some reason at this point in your code, but in general could have had any value.

`move` is a pseudo-instruction that could assemble to `addiu $a0, $t0, 0`, or an `add` or `or` with `$zero`.  Either way, the destination register is only written, so the value you leave there won't depend on whatever was there before.

Or better, just `add $a0, $t0, $t2` in the first place to do `$a0 = $t0 + $t2`.
MIPS is a 3-operand machine, don't limit yourself to always having dst and src1 be the same register.